# The wave header is corrupt using C#

Tags: c#, media, soundplayer

I am trying to play a Wav file in C# 
Some of my files come through with the error "The wave header is corrupt."
I set the Position = 0 and it still happens.

```
   using (System.Media.SoundPlayer sound = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(soundStream))
            {
                sound.Stream.Position = 0;
                sound.Play();

            }
```

If I save the Stream to a file on the disk I can play it with Media player so I know it is not corrupt.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check the first few bytes from the stream and compare them with what you expect.

Comment: about wave structure. i suggest you check the first bytes describing the wave file. [WAVE PCM soundfile format](http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/)

Answer (score 2):

[Try reloading the stream](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3d40aad9-f441-4c40-9713-a6c9a6ce733d/soundplayer-exception-the-wave-header-is-corrupt):

```
soundStream.Position = 0;

using (System.Media.SoundPlayer sound = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(soundStream))
{
    sound.Play();
}
```

Alternatively:

```
if (soundStream.CanSeek) soundStream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

Comment: The alternative worked for me when loading a stream produced with this tutorial (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dawate/2009/06/24/intro-to-audio-programming-part-3-synthesizing-simple-wave-audio-using-c/), thanks Inspector!

Answer (score 0):

This code is working fine in my app to play a mp3 stream :

```
using (var mp3 = new Mp3FileReader(new MemoryStream(buffer)))
{
    using (var pcm = WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(mp3))
    {
        using (var wave = new MemoryStream())
        {
            WaveFileWriter.WriteWavFileToStream(wave, pcm);                                                                 
            using (var sound = new SoundPlayer(wave))
            {
                sound.Play(); 
            }
        }
     }
  }
}
```